# Animation bug when switching workspace fast

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher

When I try to switch between workspaces really fast(like from workspace 6th to 1th), instead of only seeing the windows out of somewhere the wallpaper pops in between too. I don't know what causes this. I'm pretty sure this is reproducible. Here is the video demonstrating this.

[Video demonstrating the Bug](https://i.imgur.com/CXX7lGT.mp4)

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: I think it's definitely a bug on their end, but people probably aren't gonna fix this because this isn't a big issue.

Comment: hum, in my case, it is combined with some other trouble, which are very complexe to describe, but big problem

Comment: Can you share a video or something like that?

Comment: unfortunatly, as it happen in hasardous way, it is complex. I don't know when it happen. But I have changed from Gnome Vanilla to Ubuntu Gnome, and it seems, for now, that problem are solved.

Comment: Oh, I'm using ubuntu gnome and the bug has been for me since 18.04.